# How to combine debounce and Abort Controller for axios

Tags: javascript, axios, abortcontroller

I have the following search bar with

```
        <div class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Products" aria-label="Search" id="searchProduct">
        </div>
```

I would like to fire an onInput event whenever user types it will call an API.

```
const debounce = (fn, delay = 1000) => {
  let timerId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), delay);
  };
};
let controller = new AbortController();
let signal = controller.signal;

const fetchProducts = (value, signal) => {
  axios
    .get(`/FYP-ECOMMERCE/api/products?search=${value}`, {
      signal, // Pass the AbortSignal to the request
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.name === "AbortError") {
        // Handle the request abortion (e.g., ignore or log it)
        console.log("Request was aborted");
      } else {
        // Handle other errors
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
      }
    });
};

const onInput = debounce(fetchProducts, 500);

const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchProduct");

searchBar.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const term = e.target.value;
  if (term !== "") {
    controller.abort();
    controller = new AbortController();
    signal = controller.signal;
    onInput(e.target.value, signal);
  }
});
```

So my question how to combine debounce and abortcontroller , so that the previous request gets aborted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. return controller in `fethcProducts` fn === create a new controller for each request

```js
const fetchProducts = (value, signal) => {
  const controller = new AbortController();

  axios
    .get(`/FYP-ECOMMERCE/api/products?search=${value}`, {
      signal: controller.signal,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.name === "AbortError") {
        console.log("Request was aborted");
      } else {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
      }
    });
  return controller
};
```

this will give you control over the controller

2. Make the `onInput` a general function, add controller as param so that if controller exists, the current request will be aborted and fetch again with a new controller

```js
// ASIS
const onInput = debounce(fetchProducts, 500);

// TOBE
const onInput = debounce((fn, value, controller) => {
  if (controller) controller.abort();
  return fn(value); // if you make a fetch fn that returns a controller, you can reuse it.
}, 500);
```

3. Other codes

```js
let currController;

const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchProduct");

// Separate handler so that you can remove the event
function searchBarHandler(e) {
  const term = e.target.value;
  // `if` transforms the `term` as boolean to evaluate, "" will return false
  if (term) {
    currController = onInput(fetchProducts, term, currController)
  }
} 

searchBar.addEventListner("input", searchBarHandler);
```

the onInput clearly can be written in a better way, but for now, I think this should do

Comment: A better solution will be creating an AxoisProvider to control all the requests with one instance. You can abort inside the interceptor as well.

Answer (score 1):

Within your approach, the `onInput` will be called every time user click button. However, thanks to `debounce`, the truth `fetchProducts` will be called only once every 500ms and no more.

Therefore if you just simply need to call "abort" at the beginning of `fetchProducts`

```
// 1. make your controller global and `null`
let controller = null

// 2. you don't need `signal` here
const fetchProducts = (value) => {
    if (controller) {
        controller.abort()
    }

    controller = new AbortController()

    axios
        .get(`/FYP-ECOMMERCE/api/products?search=${value}`, {
             controller.signal, // from signal to controller.signal
        })
        // put the rest of your code here...
}
```

You can learn more about it with the example from MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Bonus:

Since the `controller` is outside the fetch function, if you have a `Cancel`/`Abort` button, just simply do the same

```
onCancelClick() {
    if (controller) {
        controller.abort()
    }
}
```